# error while following Tumblelog Application with Flask and MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-mongoengine

I am following tumbleblog application [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/)

my `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"] = {'DB': "sencha_web_service", 'username': "<username>", "password": "<password>"}
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "KeepThisS3cr3t"

db = MongoEngine(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I get the error:

```
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
False is not a read preference.
```

---

I tried passing in `"alias"="default"` in  `app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"]` but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your MONGODB_SETTINGS dictionary, the key for the database name should be 'db', not 'DB' (i.e. all lowercase).

The error you're getting is because the MongoEngine extension cannot find the 'db' entry in your configuration, and so uses 'default' as the database name.

**Edit**

Upon further inspection, it seems this is a bug somewhere in (Flask-)MongoEngine (or possible pymongo) where the default value of read_preference in mongoengine.connect is False instead of an actual read preference, and is not transformed to the actual default in pymongo

If you add

```
from pymongo import read_preferences
```

to your imports and

```
'read_preference': read_preferences.ReadPreference.PRIMARY
```

to your config dictionary, it should work (that's the default read_preference in pymongo)

Comment: i have tried that too..
app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"] = {
    'db': "sencha_web_service",
    'username': "<username>",
    "password": "<password>",
    "port": 27017
}

Comment: @Samuel Littley This is correct - it's a bug in the latest release.

Comment: as anyone reported this on github?

Comment: its an issue with pymongo.. downgrade pymongo to 2.7.2 and now it works fine with mongoengine-0.9.0

Comment: A quick look at the MongoDB JIRA came up with this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-719  It looks like going with the pymongo 2.7 branch is the way to go for now.

Comment: In my case I just had `mongoengine>=0.8.4,<0.9` in my `requirements.txt` file, and pymongo was being pulled in implicitly. Adding `pymongo>=2.7,<3.0` to that file fixed the issue.

Comment: The Jira ticket indicated they are not going to fix this. What would be the new way of setting this?