# Querying broken with pymongo 3.0 and Flask-MongoEngine

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I recently upgraded to pymongo 3.0 and was getting the same error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517930/error-while-following-tumblelog-application-with-flask-and-mongoengine/29518117#29518117).  The accepted answer fixed the read preferences error and my application is running.  However whenever I try to run a query I am now getting a new error and was wondering if anyone else had run into this.

Here is the Traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 756, in decorated_view
    elif not current_user.is_authenticated():
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 46, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 794, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 363, in _load_user
    return self.reload_user()
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 325, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login/app/auth/views.py", line 79, in load_user
    user.get_by_id(id)
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login/app/auth/users.py", line 23, in get_by_id
    dbUser = models.User.objects.with_id(id)
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 600, in with_id
    return queryset.filter(pk=object_id).first()
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 309, in first
    result = queryset[0]
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 160, in __getitem__
    return queryset._document._from_son(queryset._cursor[key],
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 1410, in _cursor
    **self._cursor_args)
  File "/mongo_login/mongo_login_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 929, in find
    return Cursor(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'snapshot'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open bug on MongoEngine's GitHub](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/939).

The workaround appears to be using Pymongo 2.7.2.

Comment: You can use any version of PyMongo before 3.0. PyMongo 2.8 will also work well.